# Program for managing multiple monitors to keep from rearranging Windows

Tags: windows-8, multiple-monitors, amd-graphics-card

I have a setup in use where I use *up to* four monitors. The problem is I generally switch around what I'm using and that messes up where all of my windows are.

I'm on Windows 8 and have two graphics cards. My setup is as follows:

- Monitor 1: Card 1
- Monitor 2: Card 1
- Monitor 3: Card 2
- TV 1: Card 2

I almost always have all the monitors turned on and in use. When I turn on the TV though, all of my windows get reconfigured and moved to different monitors. I don't know how to stop this.

Another configuration I use is where I have Monitors 1 and 2 plus TV in use, and I have my Xbox in use on Monitor 3. When I get done with the Xbox and switch Monitor 3 over to the PC, everything is reconfigured.

So is there a way to stop this from happening? I have the free version of Display Fusion in use but haven't seen settings to save monitor configurations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[UltraMon](http://www.realtimesoft.com/ultramon/) should be able to help. I'm not *entirely* sure how it will react to unplugging/plugging in monitors, but it ought to do the trick when it comes to reapplying your monitor configuration by saving and loading profiles.